# How to write trigger which copies value of a column of a table to another column of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table **tblBilling** and **tblTotalFee**. One of my column in **tblBilling** is named as *RemainingAmount* and in **tblTotalFee** i have another column named *Due From Previous Month*. Now what i want is whenenver i insert a value in *Remaining Amount* i want that value to be automatically inserted into *Due From Previous Month*. I am trying to write a trigger.But i just can't get it right?? Can anyone help me??

I tried:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trg_Billing_TotalFee] on [dbo].[tblBilling] 
after insert as 
insert into tblTotalFee(DueFromPreviousMonth) 
select RemainingAmount from inserted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you an example:

```
create table tblBilling (ID int identity(1000,1) primary key,
                         RemainingAmount int 
                         )
go
create table tblTotalFee (ID int identity(1000, 1) primary key,
                          DueFromPreviousMongh int)
go 
create trigger tr_tblBillingSync on tblBilling 
after insert 
as 
    insert into tblTotalFee (DueFromPreviousMongh)
    select RemainingAmount from inserted
go 
insert into tblBilling 
select 25
union all select 27
union all select 33
go
select * from tblBilling
select * from tblTotalFee
go
```

Final Output result:

```
ID     |  RemainingAmount
-------------------------
1000   |    25
1001   |    27
1002   |    33
```

```
ID     |  DueFromPreviousMongh
-------------------------
1000   |    25
1001   |    27
1002   |    33
```